# Jinja2 - global variable update in for loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm working on a configuration script for a certain service and I'd like to have it templated for our configuration management tools (Ansible). There's a particular action however, which seems to be a Jinja2 limitation (if that word is acceptable in this case) which I can't overcome:

```
{% set min = 0 %}
{% set max = 5500 %}
{% for item in list_of_items %}
    for i in {min..max}; do command {{ item }} --arg 1 commnand_stuff $i; done
    {% set min = max + 1 %}
    {% set max = max * 2 %}
#fi
{% endfor %}
```

The expected (desired) result is:
- iteration 1 - `min = 0`, `max = 5500`
- iteration 2 - `min = 5501`, `max = 11000` 
..

The actual result is:
- min and max have a constant value through all loop iterations - `min=0` and `max=5500`.

So, how do I modify a global variable in Jinja2 in for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*set* does not work inside a loop. See [assigning a variable inside a loop](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/641).

It is possible to use *loop.index* instead. The template below

```
{% for item in list_of_items %}
     {{ 5500 * (loop.index-1) + 1 }}..{{ 5500 * loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
 1..5500
 5501..11000
 11001..16500
```